# WinForms deprecate ISupportInitialize from custom control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom WinForms control which used to be descended from PictureBox (which implements ISupportInitialize) and I converted to descend from Control (which does not implement ISupportInitialize).

I have two dead methods BeginInit() and EndInit() in the control for the sole purpose of not breaking people's existing designer code.  The WinForms designer generates something like this:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.helpButton1)).BeginInit();
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.helpButton1)).EndInit();
```

That means if I take out the ISupportInitialize, nobody will even get a compiler warning that something is wrong, it will just crash at runtime with a type conversion failure (can't cast HelpButton to ISupportInitialize).

Normally to remove a deprecated property, you can mark it [Obsolete] and [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)], or simply delete it and force everyone to delete it from the designer.cs file before they can compile.  But with ISupportInitialize, it seems like you're stuck supporting it forever once it's added.

I thought of using an explicit conversion to ISupportInitialize, but that doesn't work because you can't create explicit conversions to interfaces:

```
public static explicit operator ISupportInitialize(HelpButton self)
{
    return new FakeISupportInitialize();
}
// gives error: user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed.
```

Is there any way to eliminate the interface from being designer visible without breaking existing code?

Comment: Little point in hacking this.  Simply continue implementing the interface and just do nothing in the methods.  You can postpone making the breaking change until it is truly necessary.  That moment will come some day.  Leave yourself a //TODO

Comment: It should never be truly necessary, it just offends my sensibilities to leave dead code like that sitting there :-)  I'll just do my best to forget about it.